# Load non google fonts in editor

Tags: javascript, fonts, tinymce

I have this code where I'm loading custom google fonts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let fontSizes = '5px 6px 7px 8px 9px 10px 11px 12px 13px 14px 15px 16px 18px 20px 22px 24px 26px 28px 30px 32px 36px 40px 44px 48px 54px 60px 66px 72px 80px 90px 100px 120px 150px 200px 250px';
let fonts = 'Pacifico=Pacifico; Titillium Web=titillium web,sans-serif; Sofia=sofia';
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist", "anchor", "autolink", "charmap", "code", "fullscreen", 
        "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media", 
        "preview", "searchreplace", "table", "visualblocks", 
    ],
    toolbar: "fontfamily fontsize",
    font_family_formats: fonts,
    font_css: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico, https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web, https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia",
    font_size_formats: fontSizes,
});
</script>


<textarea id="resource" name="resource"></textarea>
```

But I need to load custom fonts not from google fonts, but from disk.
I have a css file (that's loaded on the page) like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Lohit Malayalam";
    src: url("/fonts/Lohit-Malayalam.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "AnjaliOldLipi";
    src: url("/fonts/AnjaliOldLipi.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Authentic";
    src: url("/fonts/Authentic%20Signature.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Carlista Buttery";
    src: url("/fonts/Carlista%20Buttery.ttf");
}
```

How can TinyMVE load them to the front family dropdown and let the user apply the fonts to the text?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work it out. All that was needed was to add the content_css property to the TinyMCE init method, pointing to the css file that loaded the fonts:

```
content_css: 'tinymce.css',
```

When in Classic mode, TinyMCE is inside of an iframe - so the CSS file needs to be passed to TinyMCE via the content_css config option:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/add-css-options/#absolute-path-example.